# VB.NET panel addrange list of labels

Tags: vb.net, panel, addrange

In my form, I have a panel.
In a loop, I create many labels in this panel, but it's too slow.

So, it appears that create a list of labels in the loop and after add them in the panel should be more faster.

Here i my code :

```
Dim listLabels as new list(of label)
for a=0 to 100
 dim lbl as new label
 label.name="label" & a.Tostring
 listLabels.add(lbl)
next

myPanel.controls.addrange(listLabels)
```

> ERROR: Value of type 'List(of Label)' cannot be converted to 'Control()'

Can you help me please?

thks

Comment: Did you read the error message? Did you read the documentation or pay attention to Intellisense? The issue is exactly what the error message says it is. `AddRange` expects an array and you're passing it a `List(Of T)`. Either convert the list to an array, which you can find out how to do with a simple web search, or just create an array in the first place. Given that you know exactly how many elements there will be and you're using a `For` loop already, that seems the obvious option. That said, not sure why you're not adding them in the designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Control.Controls` returns a `ControlCollection` which [`AddRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.addrange?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#system-windows-forms-control-controlcollection-addrange(system-windows-forms-control())) accepts only a `Control()`(array of controls). So it's NOT a `List<Control>` which [`AddRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=net-7.0) accepts `IEnumerable<Control>`. You could use [`ToArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.toarray?view=net-7.0), it creates an array from the list:

```
myPanel.Controls.AddRange(listLabels.ToArray())
```

Since you know the size already and you need an array, you could make it more efficient:

```
Dim labels(99) as Control  ' looks odd, but has place for 100 labels
For a As Integer = 0 To 99
    Dim lbl As New Label
    lbl.Name = "label" & a.Tostring
    labels(a) = lbl
Next
Label1.Controls.AddRange(labels)
```